# Specifying the column type when using entity framework core 3.1 with SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Consider this simple class, that I will use for one of my Domain objects with **EF Core 3.1**:

```
using System;

namespace Blah.Domain
{
    public class Response
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FullResponseText { get; set; }
        public string HttpResponseCode { get; set; }
        public string TransactionId { get; set; }
        public string TransactionType { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Having a database background, I do not want to use the default type of nvarchar(max) as the column type for string values in my database (SQL Server).  How do I specify the column types to be used by EF when creating the table?

Also, do I have to include the whole `SYSTEM` Namespace just to be able to have the DateTime option available to me for my CreatedDate field or is there another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically there are two possibilities for this problem. The one is to use the attributes mentioned in the previous answer or to use the fluent API provided by EF core.

Fluent API allows you to configure precisely your database properties.

More info can be found in the [documentation](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/fluent-api-in-entity-framework-core.aspx)

Basically the required code is the following in the database context

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
        .Property(a => a.StateProvince).HasColumnType("varchar(20)");
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to add an attribute on each string value which will look like this

```
[MaxLength(50)] //Whatever int value in `maxlength` will be the size in sql
public string FullResponseText { get; set; }
[MaxLength(255)]
public string HttpResponseCode { get; set; }
etc.....
```

Or you could use `[StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5)]`

To use `[MaxLength()]` you will need `System.Collections.Generic`. For `DateTime` `System` should be the only `namespace` that you need.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: However, for creating `.net core` projects, there are plenty of namespaces that are still required for other functionality. `System` is required anyway I'm pretty sure, it does include the basic `string,int,double` etc classes and `DateTime` will throw an error without `System` however you be specific and use `system.DateTime` to only include `DateTime`